# Flagging ability for you to have your own answered questions closed

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I stumbled upon [one of my old questions that I asked a few months back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098280/fastest-and-most-supported-way-to-check-the-first-character-of-a-string), that I am entirely embarrassed that I even asked it.

The answer was soo blatantly obvious that I don't think anyone would ever reproduce this problem. However, whether it is or isn't should be an opinion left open to the community, so I was wondering if it was possible for owners of *answered* questions to flag them to be closed, and see if the community agrees to closing it?

So my question really is: Can I flag my own question to be closed, as I think the question and its answer are absolutely useless?

Also, keep in mind that the community put a lot of downvotes on the question.

Also, since the question is already answered, I cannot delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure; go right ahead. You should see a "should be closed..." option on the flag dialog, if a reason listed there fits, go ahead and flag it.

Given there's only 1 answer and it isn't exactly high-scored... You could also just delete your own question. At this point, I don't think anyone will care.

Comment: It won't let me delete it

Comment: Oh? What's the message?

Comment: I hit the delete button, and it gave me the error that it could not be deleted, because there was an existing answer

Comment: specifically: "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead"

Comment: Ok, fine. I deleted it for you (after closing it). But yes, in the future flagging it for closure yourself would've also worked. Also, I apparently need to refresh my memory on what checks are in place for deletion.

Comment: Also there was no close-reason or flag-reason for "my own question is useless"

Comment: "Duplicate" is good enough.

Comment: Interesting. Never would've thought of using that one, but I suppose it would accomplish the same objective