# Why do you have the option to vote to close your own question? Why would you ever do that?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I've never actually tried to do this to one of my own questions (for obvious reasons), but the site appears to give us the option to vote to close our own questions. The reasons are the same as the options for any other question (unclear what I'm asking, too broad, etc.).

If I really thought that my own question was so bad that it deserved to be closed, why wouldn't I just either delete it or edit to improve it?

I understand how it would be useful to be able to vote to migrate your own question, and I did see [one case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335292/flagging-ability-for-you-to-have-your-own-answered-questions-closed) where the OP wanted their own question closed.

In general, though, why would you close your own question? When would the "standard" reasons ever apply? For example, why would you vote to close your own question as unclear rather than improving or deleting it?

Comment: Closing it as duplicate might also seem reasonable. Flagging has far fewer options.

Comment: At a simple guess, the row of options at the bottom of the question are standard; you see the same as anyone else does. The fact that you are the OP gives you more options rather than less. There's probably no point in recoding the section to handle the case of the viewer being the OP, when removing the options serves no real purpose. Having those options, though rarely used, does give you some control you wouldn't have as the OP without them - duplicate being a good one. Why would someone use them? IDK, but they can, and apparently have. "Never-been-done" doesn't mean "Never-will-be-done."

Comment: Also, it's not really worthwhile to separate the privilege to vote to *reopen* your own questions from closing them.

Comment: Well, you can't delete a question with multiple answers or one up voted answer, so it's not always possible to just delete an off topic question. I can see a user choosing to close an unsalvageable question that they can't delete in hopes of preventing additional down votes.(I don't know if that would work but they might think it would.) It would at least prevent additional answers. Convincing one user to delete their answer so you can remove your question is easier than convincing five.

Comment: Related: [Should I post a question that I'm going to immediately close as as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307615/should-i-post-a-question-that-im-going-to-immediately-close-as-a-duplicate)

Comment: I did just that today. I came across a question of mine, which is almost 5 years old and should be considered "*Primarily opinion based*" today. I couldn't delete it, because it has one upvoted answer. Unfortunately it received bot answers every now and then. So I voted to close and flagged the question and with the help of a moderator it's closed now. So yes, this is a helpful feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Voting to close does not necessarily mean that the question is bad. I once asked a question on meta, but afterwards I found that the question had already been asked and answered earlier. So I voted to close my own question as a duplicate.

Comment: Right, but if it's an *exact* duplicate and the answers to the original question are good, why keep the question in the first place?

Comment: @EJoshuaS Duplicates are not bad. Let me repeat that because it seems to be a popular misconception. **Duplicates are not bad.** They serve as signposts to other questions when someone uses search words differently than the duplicate target. See [the link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307615/215552) posted by Josh Caswell about this subject.

Comment: If it really is an exact duplicate down to the phrasing, deleting it is probably a good idea. If it's not, what @MikeMcCaughan said is true: It's good for people who come here from google.