# Why would someone vote to close their own question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

At 250 rep, we earn the privilege to cast close and reopen votes on our own questions. Why would someone vote to *close* their own question? I have voted to reopen my own questions after editing them, but why would someone vote to close their own question?

Comment: If you wish you can vote to close your question as a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345429/why-do-you-have-the-option-to-vote-to-close-your-own-question-why-would-you-eve

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most obvious closure that you might want to apply yourself is to close it as a duplicate if you later happened to come across another question that had an answer to your question.

Alternatively if someone pointed out it was a typo, perhaps you'd close it for that reason once you realised your mistake, although I suspect you'd more likely just delete it unless it had been upvoted.